# how to access virtual machine from host machine's web browser?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to perform Openstack installation on Ubuntu Server 16.I am using following scenario.

> Host Machine : Windows 7 ( IP : 192.168.1.15) installed VMWare
>   application in it.
>
> Guest Machine : Ubuntu Server 16.04 (IP : provided by VMWare DHCP
>   192.168.30.178)
>
> Network Adapter : NAT ( VMNet8)

Because of NAT I am able to access **Internet** in my virtual machine.
But the problem is that ,I want to **access my virtual machine from my host machine's web browser (http)**.

```
http://192.168.30.178/
```

But because of different networks host machine (192.168.1.) and guest machine (192.168.30.), I am not able to connect it using **http://IP**

so please help me to resolve this. What IP address should I have to set for my both machines?

Comment: problem solved. I used bridged network adapter instead of NAT

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: yes.. i already posted as answer.but i dont know why it is not displaying.

Comment: Please try posting it again. It's not showing up here so it looks like it wasn't successfully posted the first time.

Answer (score 2):

I simply used **bridged** network adapter instead of NAT.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Don't forget to accept your own answer, as doing so will help future readers of this question

Comment: Also provide some of your experimentation, like why you did this, what's the (probable) cause of your issue. This will enrich your answer ;)